# how does amazon retrieve some items later(mobile application)

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am working with nodejs and react native. I am a beginner. I am working on an e-commerce application. I send a list of items say, a 100 items to my native application. The items have image information which needs to be fetched from node. So, the application sends 100 requests to node for images. I understand that is not a good practice and I need to optimize.

Is there a way where I send 20 items now and then after the user scrolled through them, I send the next 20 items. How do I keep score of how many items I have already sent to the user.

Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: Here is another library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pagination

Comment: And yet another full working example for you https://www.techup.co.in/react-native-pagination-example-infinity-list/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do infinite scrolling. To do that you can use some of the existing libraries like:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-infinite-scrolling